# Hosting issues accessing files

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have developed a PHP website, and I will add images of the hierarchy so you have a better understanding:

[Part 1 of the public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQEiS.jpg)

[Part 2 of the public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf2H1.jpg)

[Part 3 of the public_html folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1h190.jpg)

[Resources folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpwhC.jpg)

As you can see the folders contain all relevant information required.
The config file is as follows:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
defined("DS") ? null : define("DS", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined("TEMPLATE_FRONT") ? null : define("TEMPLATE_FRONT", __DIR__ .DS."templates/front");
defined("TEMPLATE_BACK") ? null : define("TEMPLATE_BACK", __DIR__ .DS."templates/back");
defined("UPLOAD_DIR") ? null : define("UPLOAD_DIR", __DIR__ .DS."uploads");
defined("DB_HOST") ? null : define("DB_HOST", "localhost"); //UPDATED IN LIVE VERSION
defined("DB_USER") ? null : define("DB_USER", "root"); //UPDATED IN LIVE VERSION
defined("DB_PASSWORD") ? null : define("DB_PASSWORD", ""); //UPDATED IN LIVE VERSION
defined("DB_NAME") ? null : define("DB_NAME", "database"); //UPDATED IN LIVE VERSION
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
require_once("functions.php");
require_once("cart.php");
?>
```

Although when I go from my login page to attempt to login, the hosting service can not find the login.php in templates/front

code on public_html/login.php is as follows:

```
<?php require_once("../resources/config.php") ?>
<?php include(TEMPLATE_FRONT . DS . "header.php") ?><div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-5">         
        <form class="" action="../resources/templates/front/login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group"><label for="">
                username<input type="text" name="mailuid" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>
             <div class="form-group"><label for="password">
                Password<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>Not a member?</p>
        <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-success">Register</a>
    </div>
<?php include(TEMPLATE_FRONT . DS . "footer.php") ?>
```

Everything works fine on the localhost side of things just not on the live host.

Comment: Have you checked the file is actually there on the live version?

Comment: Have you echoed out the file path it's trying to access to make sure it's set correctly?